# How do I restore verbose backup (bak) of notepad++ file?

Tags: backup, notepad++

My system crashed and my document is hosed. I have a restore from yesterday morning, but want to see if I can restore any of the .bak files that npp has produced for me.

I enabled the verbose backup option in settings, yet when I try to open any (of ~ 1k) of the .bak files with npp, everything is replaced by 'nul'. Is there a proper restoration procedure or am I out of luck? Thanks!